# How to work with checkbox and set value into page item?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have created an interactive report which is having column of checkboxes(Using checkbox2 function).
Report--

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(1,SERVICE_ID, P_ATTRIBUTES => 'class = "my_value"')
 "select",
       SERVICE_ID,
       SERVICENAME,
       SERVICEPRICE,
       CREATIONDATE      
  from C_SERVICES
  ORDER BY 1
```

In Function and Global Variable Declaration of the page I am using below code to set the value in page item P9_Set.
But their is an issue whenever I am unchecking the checkbox, it still updating the value into Page item. How to fix that?

```
var serviceid = [];
$('.my_value').on('click',function(){
    serviceid.push($(this).val());
    $s('P9_SET',serviceid);
    
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qpjx.png)

Comment: What is the the flow of the screen ? Is this on page submit ?

Comment: No when i checking the checkbox it should set the selected service id into item with coma  saperator.

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](http://apex-smb.blogspot.com/2015/09/report-with-checkboxes-update.html)

Comment: Thanks your answer was usefull, I don't know how to mark the question answered.

Comment: I was referring to your older questions, not this one